# Calculating an index for color changing in a sequential "stream" of images

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, difference

I'm building a simple device for my lab which actually captures images at specific intervals. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVLfd.jpg) is a sequence of images for example.

While scrolling down, you will notice that the color of the liquid inside those tubes is changing. So what I wanna achieve is to programmatically calculate an index that corresponds to the difference between the liquid colors in the two cases. I've never before dealt with image analysis and thus I would like to hear your opinions.

So far I was able to [crop a specific area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNGgy.jpg) from the images and do simple math to calculate if there is a difference. After cropping the image, I'm resizing it at 1x1 pixel in order to get the average color of it. Finally, as you can see I'm using only the Green and Blue channel of the RGB because Red one didn't have so much variance.

Here is the example code in python:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

img_dir = "./sal1000-2"
area_left = (250,340,350+16,340+37)
area_right = (419,340,419+16,340+37)
left_init = ()
right_init = ()
left = ()
right = ()

flag = 0


for file in sorted(os.listdir(img_dir)):
        if file.endswith(".jpg"):
            img = Image.open(img_dir+"/"+file)
            # CROP THE IMAGE
            cropped_left = img.crop(area_left)
            cropped_right = img.crop(area_right)
            # RESIZE THE IMAGES
            resized_left = cropped_left.resize((1,1))
            resized_right = cropped_right.resize((1,1))

            # Keep the initial values from the first image 
            if flag == 0 :
                left_init = resized_left.getpixel((0,0))
                right_init = resized_right.getpixel((0,0))
                flag = 1
            else :
                left = resized_left.getpixel((0,0))
                right = resized_right.getpixel((0,0))

                redL = left[0]-left_init[0]
                greenL = left[1]-left_init[1]
                blueL = left[2]-left_init[2]
                redR = right[0]-right_init[0]
                greenR = right[1]-right_init[1]
                blueR = right[2]-right_init[2]

                print("LEFT: \t", str(greenL-blueL), "\t RIGHT: \t", str(greenR-blueR), file)
```

I then used R to plot the printed values and I got a plot like this one:
[image]

With the right tube is denoted with red while the green is the left one.

As you can see the algorithm can discriminate the two tubes at the very beginning and I don't know if that's true or its some kind of artifact due to the code's logic.

Any ideas or hints are welcomed.

Comment: How does your device that captures images differ from a camera? What range of colours are you expecting it to detect? Have you considered adding a colour calibration card (e.g. Spyder Checker) to your scene so you can correct lighting differences?

Comment: Actually, it is a camera. And more specifically is a Raspberry Pi camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts, and some code...

If you are interested in **colour** changes, JPEG is generally not the best choice of format because it does chroma subsampling, i.e. it reduces the colour accuracy in favour of the brightness accuracy because the human eye is less sensitive to colour variations than brightness variations - see [downsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Downsampling). So, see if you can save in PNG or PPM format off your camera, that may help.

Also, as you are interested in **colour** changes, you may be better off in [HSL or HSV colourspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) because that will vary less as a result of any variations in lighting. So, I would suggest you consider working with Hue which represents what we would call *"colour"*. That has the benefit that you will just get one value, i.e. Hue, rather than three, i.e. Red, Green and Blue.

So, with that said, the code could look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
from glob import glob

area_L = (250,340,350+16,340+37)
area_R = (419,340,419+16,340+37)

files = glob("f*.jpg")                                                                    
files.sort()                                                                              

for f in files: 
   print('Processing {}'.format(f))
   img = Image.open(f).convert('HSV')
   H, S, V = img.split()
   cropped_L = H.crop(area_L)
   cropped_R = H.crop(area_R)
   resized_L = cropped_L.resize((1,1))
   resized_R = cropped_R.resize((1,1))
   L = resized_L.getpixel((0,0))
   R = resized_R.getpixel((0,0))
   print('Left Hue: {}, Right Hue: {}'.format(L,R))
```

And the output is:

```
Processing f00.jpg
Left Hue: 66, Right Hue: 14
Processing f01.jpg
Left Hue: 58, Right Hue: 21
Processing f02.jpg
Left Hue: 57, Right Hue: 26
Processing f03.jpg
Left Hue: 58, Right Hue: 27
Processing f04.jpg
Left Hue: 59, Right Hue: 27
Processing f05.jpg
Left Hue: 57, Right Hue: 26
Processing f06.jpg
Left Hue: 57, Right Hue: 28
Processing f07.jpg
Left Hue: 60, Right Hue: 25
Processing f08.jpg
Left Hue: 60, Right Hue: 25
Processing f09.jpg
Left Hue: 58, Right Hue: 25
Processing f11.jpg
Left Hue: 59, Right Hue: 25
Processing f12.jpg
Left Hue: 59, Right Hue: 25
Processing f13.jpg
Left Hue: 57, Right Hue: 25
Processing f14.jpg
Left Hue: 60, Right Hue: 24
Processing f15.jpg
Left Hue: 58, Right Hue: 28
Processing f16.jpg
Left Hue: 60, Right Hue: 29
Processing f17.jpg
Left Hue: 60, Right Hue: 32
Processing f18.jpg
Left Hue: 60, Right Hue: 33
Processing f19.jpg
Left Hue: 58, Right Hue: 34
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It seems reasonable the values of the right tube to be increased but I cannot understand this big difference between them in the first image. I would expect to have more or less same values in the beginning. But 66 VS 14? That's overwhelming. Maybe its due to JPG format.